# max-width not changing width of my divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been following a [css and html tutorial at udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud304/lessons/2617868617/concepts/27713785720923).

My code is this:

```css
.image{
  max-width: 50%;
}
.app{
  display: flex;
}
.description{
  color: red;
  max-width: 705px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">My App</h1>
<div class="app">
    <div class="image">image</div>
    <div class="description">some long text</div>
</div> <!-- /.app -->
```

When I increase `max-width` of the image div, image div remains the same width no matter what.

But when I increase `max-width` of description, it changes accordingly.

Also when I change `max-width` to `width` it changes also the 460px and occupies more space than with `max-width`.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

`max-width` doesn't set the width of an element.

It tells your divs: *this is how wide you can get (starting from 0, content width, or `min-width`)*

Your divs have a `max-width: 50%` (`.image`) and `max-width: 705px` (`.description`).

If there were no content in either div, the width would be zero.

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
.image {
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.description {
  color: red;
  max-width: 705px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">My App</h1>
<div class="app">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.app -->
```

If the content width were to be less than the `max-width`, the divs would take the content width.

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.image {
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.description {
  color: red;
  max-width: 705px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">My App</h1>
<div class="app">
  <div class="image">xxx</div>
  <div class="description">xxxx</div>
</div>
<!-- /.app -->
```

If the content were to be more than the `max-width`, then `max-width` would come into play.

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.image {
  max-width: 10%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.description {
  color: red;
  max-width: 70px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">My App</h1>
<div class="app">
  <div class="image">image image image image image image image</div>
  <div class="description">some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text</div>
</div>
<!-- /.app -->
```